# 301 redirection instead of 302 redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have used this code so far in my local (it's working fine).

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /projectname/

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

redirect 301 /projectname/index/ http://localhost/projectname/
redirect 301 /projectname/about/index/ http://localhost/projectname/about/
redirect 301 /projectname/agent/index/ http://localhost/projectname/agent/
redirect 301 /projectname/privacy/index/ http://localhost/projectname/privacy/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule .* $0 [R]
```

I place this in root .htaccess file. But i have three subfolders like about, agent, privacy also.

I used this code for

1. remove .php extension (except index pages in all folders include root).
2. add trailing slash
3. remove more than one trailing slashes
4. remove index.php in all folders (including root and subfolders).

(Note: Same thing applied for all pages inside subfolder as well)

But these pages redirected from 302 and then redirect 301.
I need to redirect only 301 include all the options specified above (points).

Any one please amend these redirection rules.

Any one please help me ?

Comment: `R` flag is a *302* by default. You'd need to specify `R=301` everywhere

Comment: Its working with 301 but its taking two 301 redirection...
I need to do it in one redirection for seo purpose...
Can you please help me with that...

Comment: What is the purpose for last 2 lines in htaccess?

Comment: @SarvanKumar You end up with a redirect chain because you match multiple rules one after the other. See my answer with a simplified logic

Comment: Last two lines for remove more than one trail slashes.. @mx0

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess could be simplified this way in order to respect your criteria

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/

# redirect "*/index.php" to "*/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+/)?index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# redirect "*/page.php" to "*/page/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

# rewrite back "*/page/" to "*/page.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: if i access like this,
https://test/index.php///
Its not working..
Trail slash will be one...

Comment: Why would you add voluntarily additional trailing slashes ? That doesn't make sense. Also, sending a `404` (not found) by default is ok in this case. What do you mean by `not working` for subfolders index ?